# How to Voronoi-fracture with Chebychev, Manhattan, or Minkowski?

Tags: modeling

[image: Voronoi procedural shading with EEVEE or Cycles]

My question relates to Blenders Voronoi or cell fracture feature.
How to fracture with a different algorithm?
I would like to get polygons fractured with the Chebychev, Manhattan, or Minkowski algorithm.
Procedural shading may work for some shading, however I wish to do it polygonal.
In the screenshot there is the procedural shading node for it to get some idea what I refer to.

Comment: So you don't need fracture it in volume. You want to split plane by procedural texture, right?

Comment: yes exactly what I would like to do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible natively. And there isn't an easy way ...

You can try create black&white image. I wanted suggest to use newly implemented *Trace to GreasePencil*, but it didn't work without issues for this kind of image.

[image]

So probably would be better to use other app to vectorise (trace) image as Line Art and import as SVG back to Blender, Convert to Mesh, Delete by Limited Dissolve - angle 35°in this case (or dicrease curve resolution to 1 before convert to mesh), Merge by Distance.

[image]

Add Plane, select both objects, switch to edit mode and use **Knife Project** to split plane into parts.

[image]

[image]

---

There was a script FractureMe2d with this feature - split plane by image. It was a part of [FractureMe](http://fungus.ffa.vutbr.cz/%7Enovak/dwnflz/crackme/) file from pildanovak for Blender2.49 that worked at glance. Abandoned.

[image]

Comment: I think this is the solution to get it done. MANY THANKS for your time explaining this.

Comment: I gave you credit over at DAZ - again THANKS

Comment: I dont know what does it means, but sounds like something good :) So thanks :)