# How to cut out mesh into colored png borders

Tags: mesh

[image]

I want to cut out these provinces of the united states, this is what my intended result (kind of) would look like:[image]

Comment: I did not want to cut it out all individually so I want to use an image to cut them out for me, I tried converting it to svg but I got a buggy mess instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Voronoi-fracture with Chebychev, Manhattan, or Minkowski?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205047/how-to-voronoi-fracture-with-chebychev-manhattan-or-minkowski)

Comment: I don't see the relation between the two images. Even the contours don't match, I see just a very slight resemblance.

Comment: Oh I didn't expect that to be a problem for some reason, I was really sleepy, I found a version of the map with borders so that will make things a LOT easier when i get back to it